# Affect translateX number as browser window scales down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using css

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

to horizontally center an image `<img>`.
Is there a way to gradually increase the translateX number as the window is scaled down horizontally? With increase I mean going from -50% to -51% to -52% etc. etc.

**[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/yn9pb3kL/6/)**

Comment: media queries and breakpoints

Comment: Thanks @Adam Wolski, but I was hoping for a smooth way. This would mean a LOT of breakpoints.

Comment: clearly you have some wrong conception, your js fiddle does not make much sense. Why div3 has `width:100vw;` and then it is centered? What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: You can  ignore "mydiv1". Mydiv3 is centered because when the window is scaled the image no longer fits in its container and I want the image to be become hidden at both sides. As for what I trying to achieve: as the browser window is scaled down horizontally I want the image to gradually sit more and more left of center of its container.